# Recompiling MACSim for the S-Block

Tags: c++, matlab, dll

I am trying to configure MACSimJX to work with Matlab R2012b. I have gone through the readme file. When I run the file make.m to produce the macsim.dll file, I get the following error:

```
--> "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\sys\perl\win32\bin\perl.exe" "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\bin\win64"\link_borland_mex.pl "macsim".dll -aa -c -Tpd -x -Gn -L\"C:\Borland\bcc55\"\lib\32bit -L\"C:\Borland\bcc55\"\lib -L\"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\extern\lib\win32\borland\bc54\" libmx.lib libmex.lib libmat.lib c0d32.obj import32.lib cw32mt.lib "macsim.def" -L"C:\macsimjx\MyTools\MACSim\lib\SimClassLib\code\bin"  @C:\Users\IGARCI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_KsGTY6\mex_tmp.rsp   

Filename - C:\Users\IGARCI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_KsGTY6\mex_tmp.rspTurbo Incremental Link 5.00 Copyright (c) 1997, 2000 Borland 
Error: Unresolved external '_mxGetPr' referenced from C:\USERS\IGARCIAVEGA\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\MEX_KSGTY6\MACSIM.OBJ 
Error: Unresolved external '_mxCalloc' referenced from C:\USERS\IGARCIAVEGA\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\MEX_KSGTY6\MACSIM.OBJ 
Error: Unresolved external '_mxGetN' referenced from C:\USERS\IGARCIAVEGA\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\MEX_KSGTY6\MACSIM.OBJ 
Error: Unresolved external '_mxIsComplex' referenced from C:\USERS\IGARCIAVEGA\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\MEX_KSGTY6\MACSIM.OBJ 
Error: Unresolved external '_mxIsNumeric' referenced from C:\USERS\IGARCIAVEGA\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\MEX_KSGTY6\MACSIM.OBJ 
Error: Unresolved external '_mxGetM' referenced from C:\USERS\IGARCIAVEGA\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\MEX_KSGTY6\MACSIM.OBJ 
Error: Unresolved external '_mxCreateDoubleMatrix_730' referenced from C:\USERS\IGARCIAVEGA\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\MEX_KSGTY6\MACSIM.OBJ 

  C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2012B\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Link of 'macsim.dll' failed.
```

Any idea?